# Magento 2: "https://packages.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, package

I keep getting this warning when I run `composer update` in my Magento 2 install.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Your configuration does not allow connections to http://packages.firegento.com/packages.json. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
http://packages.firegento.com could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
The "https://packages.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
https://packages.magento.com could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

Still it seems like the update goes fine everytime but I wonder how can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firegento problem was caused by the repository being globally declared.

Thus I had to remove the repository from `/home/<user>/.composer/config.json`

Regarding the magento issue, similar problem, it was globally declared I ended up running:

```
composer config -g -- repositories.magento composer https?://repo.magento.com
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two issues in there:

1.) connection to a http composer repository `http://packages.firegento.com` - changing this to `https://packages.firegento.com` should solve this (please note that this repository is not included in a default Magento install)

2.) `https://packages.magento.com/` is the old `https://repo.magento.com/` from Magento 2 beta days. This has been shut down so suggest removing this from your `composer.json`

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users (Centos 6,7)
Check your name servers that you have in /etc/resolv.conf working properly with the below command

nslookup www.google.com

If it is not working used the google public name server at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Raphael's answer works and it should be used when you want to change the magento repository URL in composer config to `repo.magento.com`

Alternatively, following will also get rid of the error and it can be used if you want to unset the magento repository in global composer config instead of changing the URL:

```
composer config -g --unset repositories.magento
```