# Trying to upgrade from 2.1.6 to 2.1.7 and getting a composer error

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I am trying to upgrade from Magento 2.1.6 to 2.1.7 using this https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/magento2/9022/upgrading-magento#t=201704130958117574309 as my guide.

I type in- `composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 --no-update`

Then the next step when I run composer update I get this error-

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package magento/project-community-edition 2.1.6 is satisfiable by magento/project-community-edition[2.1.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

What is causing this error?

**Edit:**

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.1.6",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.7",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.1.6",
    "magento/project-community-edition": "2.1.7"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "magento": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
    }

},
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
}
```

@RamaChandran I followed the link you mentioned and tried this

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://packages.magento.com/"
    }
]
```

When I do that I get this error

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     Your configuration does not allow connections to http://packages.magento.com/packages.json. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.

I switched the url to https and now get this error-

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>    The "https://packages.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
>    failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Comment: Did you remove the vendor folder?

Comment: I did not remove the vendor folder. Should I? Seems like there is a lot of files in there.

Comment: You can rename the vendor folder so you can restore it when something broke. But I don't think that's the issue here. Could you post your `composer.json`?

Comment: please post your composer.json file. for refer this link https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/issues/26

Comment: @ooxi I have added the composer file. I did change "prefer-stable": true, to false just to see if that would work but it didn't.

Comment: @RamaChandran Added response to main post.

Comment: try repo.magento.com and check again

composer config -g -- repositories.magento composer https?://repo.magento.com

Comment: @RamaChandran Could you clarify? I am showing I already have repo.magento.com in my composer file.

Comment: okey  repo.magento.com correct

Comment: @RamaChandran I tried what you were suggestion and all it says is "You have new mail"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your require section is conflicting with your current package name (and is being a bit recursive).

First, let's peg your composer project version to the next version number:

```
"version": "2.1.7",
```

Then update your require section:

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.7",
    "composer/composer": "<=1.0.0-beta1",
    "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.1.7",
},
```

You don't need to require `magento/project-community-edition` - that's the name of the project you're attempting to update. See: `"name": "magento/project-community-edition"`. You're also loading an out-of-date `magento/data-migration-tool` but I'd guess you've already done the migration. You may be able to remove this entry as well. Finally, the core Magento repos suggest the `<=1.0.0-beta1` version for `composer/composer` so we should probably stick to that.

Under your `"repositories"` the second

```
"magento": {
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
}
```

is extraneous and can be removed.

Comment: So I did exactly what you said and tried to run composer update. When I did that I got the [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
Your configuration does not allow connections to http://packages.magento.com/packages.json. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details. Error again.

Comment: I did a quick google and it seems that the `packages.magento.com` repo is likely cached in your composer `config.json` file - which can be in various locations depending on your OS. (Usually in your user folder.)

They suggested this command to correct the setting: `composer config -g -- repositories.magento composer https?://repo.magento.com`

Comment: I found this "https://packages.magento.com/ is the old https://repo.magento.com/ from Magento 2 beta days. This has been shut down so suggest removing this from your composer.json" -from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123764/magento-2-https-packages-magento-com-packages-json-file-could-not-be-downlo     So with your fixes and removing that it seems to be working. Any idea if I have to do this every time I do a minor Magento upgrade?

Comment: Alternatively you'll have to locate your composer config.json file. On Windows this should be under `<your_user_directory>\AppData\Roaming\Composer`. On most *nix systems this is under `/home/<user>/.composer` or `/home/<user>/.config/composer`. On OSX it's `/Users/<user>/.composer`. Check the contents and either remove the entry or delete the file if there's nothing in it that you need.

Comment: Once it's removed from that config.json file it shouldn't return. I personally have no settings in that file at all and I've never had Magento drop anything else into it. (The auth.json file, on the other hand, probably stores your HTTPS credentials to access `repo.magento.com`.)